# Xamarin Android Player Drag and Drop not working?

Tags: android, android-emulator, xamarin

I had xamarin android player installed on my machine and I could install APKs on it just through dragging and dropping it inside the device until I have updated it today.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/android-player/

Does anyone have other ideas other than dragging and dropping?

Answer (score 0):

Reverting back to the emulator previous version instead of the latest one was the only solution I had. The emulator is still new I know but Xamarin hasn't any communication channels that allow me inform them with the problem.

Comment: http://forums.xamarin.com/categories/xamarin-player-private-alpha is probably best way to report this kind of things... Or maybe report bug https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Xamarin%20Android%20Player

Comment: Hi Ahmed, do you have a link to the version (or at least version number) of player that works buy any chance. I would appreciate if you could put it into your answer. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm no longer using it. It was unstable and I considered moving to genny motion instead